# install private R package in docker file

Tags: r, dockerfile

I am trying to use Docker and ShinyProxy for the first time and I am struggling a lot at the very beginning of the process.

I developed some shiny apps that work well locally and I am thinking about deploying them in some articles of my website.

Those shiny apps use 2 packages that I have coded myself and that are located locally on my computer.

How can I install those private R packages in my Dockerfile so that the 'container' will have access to them???

I have seen tons of examples installing packages from CRAN, which I have no problem with. However, I cannot find the way to install my own packages from a local repository.

At the moment, I have a folder called 'DockerEC' with the following files:

```
'App.R'
'run_app.R'
'installpackages.R'
'Dockerfile'
```

In my local shiny apps, I install those packages simply using:

```
install.packages("/Users/name/Documents/R/Package_NAME", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I wrote this line of code in my installpackages.R file but I cannot Run this file as I get an error: 'no such file or directory'.

I used

```
COPY /Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC/installpackages.R /Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC/installpackages.R
```

and then

```
RUN Rscript /Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC/installpackages.R
```

in my docker file but don't get why I am not finding the file?

Anyone has a concrete example of a way of installing private R package in the dockerfile? I am missing a concrete example to understand how to do it...

Answer (score 3):

Try the `Dockerfile` below, it works for me:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.1

RUN mkdir ./private_pkgs

COPY /Users/name/Documents/R/your_package.tar.gz ./private_pkgs/your_package.tar.gz

RUN R -e "install.packages('private_pkgs/your_package.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"
```

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know, thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: Without success :( 

Here is the beginning of my Dockerfile: 

`FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.3  

COPY . /Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC
WORKDIR /Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC  

COPY /Users/name/Documents/R/my_package.tar.gz /Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC/private_pkgs/my_package.tar.gz`

Comment: I think the issue is directory `/Users/name/Documents/R/DockerEC` doesn't exist on the image, you need to make it with `RUN mkdir`. Try using the `Dockerfile` I posted above, you only should need to change the name of the package from `your_package` to whatever you have it named