# Installing a private/local R Package into Docker Image

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

Similar to the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531263/install-private-r-package-in-docker-file), I am unable to install a custom, local/private R package into a Docker image for a shiny application I have been working on. All the remote packages from GitHub and CRAN that I need install just fine. But my local application cannot be found after attempting to run the docker image.

`Error in library(blah) : there is no package called ‘blah’`

I have built my local package on Windows 10 using `devtools::build()`, which produces a `.tar.gz` file which, as far as I know, is *supposed to* be interoperable between Windows and Linux (correct me if I'm wrong).

The file path for installation of this private package in my Dockerfile is correct:

`RUN R -e "install.packages('C:/Users/<user>/Documents/<subfolder>/blah.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"`

I've tested the installation outside of Docker, so as far as I know, it should work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't a path directory for the .tar.gz source file that I was installing from; the problem was that there was a dependency in my private package that was preventing its successful installation. I was able to figure this out by inserting `list.dirs()` and `list.files()` in my app script to understand the file structure of my docker image, confirming that my .tar.gz file was in the place I expected to find it.

As using `RUN R -e "install.packages('blah.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"` within the dockerfile does not yield errors if the package fails to install, I found the problem by instead inserting the installation snippet (`install.packages("blah")`) into my app file itself, where the code gave me an error (I have a global.R file, others might use app.R). By installing the package this way (albeit temporarily), I was able to view the code output and see exactly why it was failing. I added the new dependency to my dockerfile, and now my package can install from source without error.

Answer (score 0):

Command in Dockerfile runs **inside** the building image, so it cannot reach files elsewhere in the host file system. You may:

- copy the file to the build directory (build context, the directory where you run `docker build`)
- in `Dockerfile`: copy the file to the image explicitly, then the R command may reach the file inside the image.

  ```
  # copy from the build context to the image:
  # <HOST_BUILD_DIR>/blah.tar.gz => <IMAGE_WORK_DIR>/blah.tar.gz
  COPY blah.tar.gz . 
  # R locates <IMAGE_WORK_DIR>/blah.tar.gz inside the image
  RUN R -e "install.packages('blah.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"
  ```

Some references:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not work- same error, even after running `docker prune system` prior to implementing your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you could try use absolute path in like `RUN R -e "install.packages('<IMAGE_WORK_DIR>/blah.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"` as I am not familiar with R about how it locates files. Does the R installation command report any error?